# Running ASP.NET OAuth server under a virtual application returns 404 for /token

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, oauth, virtual-directory

I want to run our WebAPI application as a virtual application in IIS but I cannot get authentication to work. I don't know what to use for `TokenEndpointPath` in `OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions` to successfully login.

Currently, the virtual application path is `/app`, so I thought `TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/app/token")` might work. But it returns a 404. Using just `/token` also returns a 404 when I post to `/app/token`.

How do I configure the OAuth server to answer my token requests?

Comment: I'm not sure that will work under a virtual path because the auth server needs to register itself as the issuer, which in turn is used in the resource server (api usually) to validate that the token came from that source. The virtual path would need a host header to register it as the token provider. I'm basing this off of what I know of the complicated enigma called oAuth so it might be possible but I've never seen it done. I would be interested in seeing the answer if you do figure out a way.

Comment: @StephenBrickner: Unfortunately, I don't understand half of what you're saying, but if you're arguing that it can't be done, put that argument into an answer so that I can accept it. We stopped pursuing this path after 2h of fighting...

Comment: @Oliver: do you have solution for this problem?

Comment: @kienct89: Unfortunately, no. And even more problems occurred in association with running our Web API application as a virtual application, that's why we stopped going down that road.

Answer (score 0):

What I was saying is I think you have to register the issuer (the token server). Notice below the "issuer" in the resource server matches the AccessTokenFormat in the auth server. It is validating that the token in fact came from that domain. I'm not sure how you would pass that validation with a virtual path.

```
//Auth server
public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
    {
        AllowInsecureHttp = true,
        TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/oauth2/token"),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
        Provider = new CustomOAuthProvider(),
        AccessTokenFormat = new CustomJwtFormat("http://yourHostName")
    };

   // OAuth 2.0 Bearer Access Token Generation
   app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
}

//Resource server (API)
public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var issuer = "http://yourHostName";
    var audience = "00000000000000000000000";
    var secret = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode("yourSecret");

    app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
    new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
        AllowedAudiences = new[] { audience },
        IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
        {
            new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, secret)
        },
        Provider = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider
        {
            OnValidateIdentity = context =>
            {
                context.Ticket.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("newCustomClaim", "newValue"));
                return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
            }
        }
    });
}
```